# Is there a way for the console to print 2 lines when calling a function

Tags: r

So I'm building a program in R that defines a function that takes a vector calculates it's length, prints the length and if it's bigger than 10 type "YES" otherwise type "NO"

```
index<-function(x){
n<-length(x)
n
if(n>10){
"YES"
}
else{
"NO"
}
}
```

However when I define a vector and call the function it only prints "YES" or "NO" and not the length.

```
> x<-c(2,5,2,6,8,2,12)
> index(x)
[1] "NO"
> x<-c(2,5,2,6,8,2,12, 5,2,4,6,3,8)
> index(x)
[1] "YES"
```

Is there a way for the console to print out both the length and the "YES" or "NO"?

Comment: `print(n)` instead of n will do the job

Comment: My suggestion would be to use `message(n)` instead of `n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a function that combines both the n and the yes/no in one function, you could do:

```
index<-function(x){
  n<-length(x)
  if(n>10){
    paste(n,"YES")
  }
  else{
    paste(n,"NO")
  }
}
```

For example,

```
> x<-c(2,5,2,6,8,2,12)
> index(x)
[1] "7 NO"
> x<-c(2,5,2,6,8,2,12, 5,2,4,6,3,8)
> index(x)
[1] "13 YES"
```

Answer (score 2):

When you want two different object types returned, I think it's appropriate to use a list.

```
index <- function(x) {
    n <- length(x)
    list(length = n, n10 = if(n > 10) "YES" else "NO")
}

index(1:8)
# $length
# [1] 8
#
# $n10
# [1] "NO"

index(1:23)
# $length
# [1] 23
#
# $n10
# [1] "YES"
```

Comment: A list is definitely more principled than a single string (which would need to be broken down and parsed if you needed the individual components).